# Localstack throws The security token included in the request is invalid when it tries to send sqs message

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-sqs

Localstack throws  The security token included in the request is invalid when it tries to send a message.

It seems like it tries to connect to real AWS.

Below is my configuration:

```
     companion object {

        @Container
        val localstack: LocalStackContainer = LocalStackContainer(DockerImageName.parse("localstack/localstack:3.0.0"))
            .withServices(Service.SQS)
          

        private lateinit var sqsAsyncClient: SqsAsyncClient
        private lateinit var url: String

        @BeforeClass
        @JvmStatic
        fun setup() {
            localstack.start()

            sqsAsyncClient = SqsAsyncClient.builder()
                .endpointOverride(localstack.getEndpointOverride(Service.SQS))
                .credentialsProvider(
                    StaticCredentialsProvider.create(
                        AwsBasicCredentials.create(
                            localstack.accessKey, localstack.secretKey
                        )
                    )
                )
                .region(Region.of(localstack.region))
                .build()


            url = sqsAsyncClient.createQueue(
                CreateQueueRequest.builder().queueName("test").build()
            ).get().queueUrl()
        }

        @DynamicPropertySource
        @JvmStatic
        fun dynamicProperties(registry: DynamicPropertyRegistry) {
            registry.add("spring.cloud.aws.sqs.queues.url") { url }
        }

    }
```